# NodeJS - Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL: address not available

Tags: node.js, lan

I am running a Node app that should be hosted on a local server.
At the moment, I am sending just a plaintext response.

```
const http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {ContentType: 'text/plain'});
  res.end("test");
});
```

When I listen to the localhost everything works fine and I am able to send the request from my browser.

```
server.listen(3000, '127.0.0.1'); // works fine, on the same machine
```

However, if I try to listen to a port on my LAN network by typing the router's IP, I get an error.

```
server.listen(3000, '192.168.0.1'); // causes an error
```

```
Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL: address not available 192.168.0.1:3
000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1253:19)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1318:12)
    at doListen (net.js:1451:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:1
9)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:7
57:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1297:8)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:1
9)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

I have tried this with my public IP address unsuccessfully. 
Is there any way to listen to a port on a LAN server so that I can send requests from any computer on the network?

Also, I would later like my application to run on any computer on any LAN network. How can I dynamically add my host?

Comment: Have you try IP 0.0.0.0 (will listen on all IP) ? server.listen(3000, '0.0.0.0');

Comment: You need set you server ip not your router ip, then you need to open a port in your router and add one port forwarding to your server from your router. For example if you server is listening at port 80 and you have port 5458 listening in your router you should redirect to your server ip plus its port like (192.168.0.x:80)...

Comment: @DavidAgustinMelgar How do I now which port is listening in my router? Where do I do the redirect? What exact code should be in my app? A bit clearer explanation would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: you need to open it, go to Port Forward in the router's setting and there you need set the router port to machine IP eg  router:8080 to => 192.168.0.4:80 
8080 is an example.
This is for accessing from internet to you webserver in you LAN.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this

`server.listen(3000, '0.0.0.0');`

you can access your node application from other machine

e.g

your lan ip is 192.168.0.101 then you can browse 192.168.0.101:3000 from other machine

Comment: This still only listens to my localhost (127.0.0.1:3000), but not to 192.168.0.101:3000

Comment: what os you're using? is 192.168.0.101 is your machine's ip address?

Comment: My ip address now appears to be 192.168.0.104, and it's now working with that address! Thanks!

Comment: This causes the error to not happen, but I still can't reach it in my browser with my ip :3000 ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Answer (score 6):

I got this error, the issue was I had a VPN connected

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Turning off the VPN works for me, I just turn it on again once NUXT has started building. Sometimes it though happens even if I have no VPN connected and even if I restart the laptop.

Answer (score 4):

Be careful with your IP.
Sometimes it changes. When I work with Node I have to check the `ipconfig` in Shell... I hope with that it could help if someone else have the same problem...

Comment: Wow, it worked, thanks! I thought googling "what is my ip" would give me the correct ip but that wasn't the case. It didn't give me the IPv4 address. So, ipconfig resolved the issue for me

Answer (score 3):

### Another reason

Sometimes this will happen when you are running the app inside a container and try to use your private ip (e.g 192.168.10.2) inside the container. Since container is an isolated environment, It doesn't know about your private ip.

### Solution

You should use 0.0.0.0:PORT to run the node js app and then bind this port to your private ip. For example in docker compose you should do it like this:

```
ports:
   - "192.168.10.4:PORT:PORT"
```

Answer (score 1):

The right IP address actually turned out to be 192.168.0.104. 
The IP address of a server machine should be used, not that of a router.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking port and ip combination both. I just answered in context of sls here. but same would be applicable here as well.

> https://github.com/dherault/serverless-offline/issues/1015

If it's a port problem, you can fix by killing the specific port

> kill $(lsof -ti:PORT)

** change PORT with specific port number

If it's ip problem or not, same can be verified if that ip is still allocated to the machine in consideration.

> ifconfig | grep ine

this command is for mac machine but a similar variant can be used for linux machines.

Answer (score 0):

If this help someone in my case the issue was the I'm working on MacOS and I forget to add the localhost to the host files like this:

127.0.0.1 mydomain.localhost